# Access short url instead of long url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I store my php files in source directory, so when i want to access them i have to type the full url path **http://example.com/source/login.php**.

How can i convert the url to **http://example.com/login** without moving files from the source directory??

So i can access www.example.com/login where the login.php file will still be in **source folder** *(source/login.php)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think this implementation of `.htaccess` will do what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /foo/bar.php to /foo/bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ source/$1.php [L]
```

The first block turns on the `mod_rewrite` engine to begin the rewrite process.

The second block tells the browser to perform an HTTP redirect with a status of 302 meaning repeat the request in the manner that we return, in this case `/foo/bar` without the extension.

The third block tells the server to take requests that can't be found such as a file with no extension like `foo/bar` and internally redirect the request to the same directory with the `.php` extension added.

**EDIT:**

I missed the final rewrite requirement in the original answer. Thanks to [*@JoshJ*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182891/josh-j) for pointing out the fix.

Comment: The final rule should be `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ source/$1.php` to satisfy OP's requirement.

Comment: @JoshJ Thanks for the update. I missed that last part. Edited the answer and credited you with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use htaccess rules. The process of "shortening" the urls is called "url rewriting". Copy the following code and paste it to the root folder of your localhost with the file name ".htaccess".

```
      Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
      RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
      RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ source/$1.php
```

The above code basically rewrites the url to the one you specified. It works for all the urls in the same pattern.

Additionally you may want to see this blog post for more information and facing the usual gotchas.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Happy hacking

Comment: The final rule should be `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ source/$1.php` to satisfy OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work it was throwing me a 500 error. I fixed it using this code.

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ source/$1.php [L]
```